# why function code can not be instead with operation code in R-format MIPS instruction?

Tags: mips

Only R-Format instruction has function code defined. I noticed the operation code is zero for R-format instructions. Why function code is designed to identify a specific operation, rather than operation code for R-format instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIPS32 has something like 160 different instructions (give or take a few depending on the exact revision), while the *opcode* field is fixed at 6 bits.

Obviously you cannot encode 160 unique values in 6 bits. Therefore, some instructions share the same opcode and use other bits in the instruction word to uniquely identify the instruction.

For R-Type instructions, the opcode 0 (aka *SPECIAL*) or 0x1C (aka *SPECIAL2*) is used. And the 6 least significant bits of the instruction word - called the *function* bits - determine the exact instruction.